# Conditional declaring arrays in two-dimensional char array?

Tags: c#, arrays, conditional-statements, declare

I have a two-dimensional char array declared with four strings.

```
private static string string1 = "abcde";
private static string string2 = "ABCDE";
private static string string3 = "12345";
private static string string4 = "67890";

public string selectChars(bool includeOne, bool includeTwo, bool includeThree, bool includeFour)
{
   char[][] charGroups = new char[][] 
   {
       string1.ToCharArray(),
       string2.ToCharArray(),
       string3.ToCharArray(),
       string4.ToCharArray()
   };
}
```

I want to declare and initialize the array such that the string add is conditional based on four bool flags. For example, if includeOne and includeThree are true, I want to end up with a charGroup[2][5] having used string1 and string 3.

(This is existing code where I don't want to radically change the rest of the code. if I can conditionally declare the array in that block, I'm done.)

Comment: Would you explain your problem by sample.

Comment: I added a little more meat to my description. Hope it's enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manner you want is like a list, so it's better implement it by list and then return an array by `ToArray`:

```
public string selectChars(bool includeOne, bool includeTwo, bool includeThree, bool includeFour)
{
        List<char[]> chars = new List<char[]>();
        string string1 = "";
        if (includeOne)
            chars.Add(string1.ToCharArray());
        if(includeTwo) ....

        char[][] charGroups = chars.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: That works. I figured I was going to have to go to a more dynamic structure, but was asking in case I had overlooked a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the VM going but I think this should work...

```
private static string string1 = "abcde";
private static string string2 = "ABCDE";
private static string string3 = "12345";
private static string string4 = "67890";

public string selectChars(bool includeOne, bool includeTwo, bool includeThree, bool includeFour)
{
   char[][] charGroups = new char[][] 
   {
       include1 ? string1.ToCharArray() : new char[0],
       include3 ? string2.ToCharArray() : new char[0],
       include3 ? string3.ToCharArray() : new char[0],
       include4 ? string4.ToCharArray() : new char[0]
   };
}
```

If all you want to do is include the string as a character array if their respective flag is set then I think this will do the trick.  It is using the conditional operator to include the left side of ':' (if includeX is true) otherwise include the right side.

Comment: Will that add empty arrays? IOW, will there be four jagged arrays in the charGroup array of which some may be arrays of length zero, or an exact number of arrays?

Answer (score -2):

1) Count up how many strings need to be added (how many of the flags are true).

2) `char[][] charGroups = new char[count][];` (might need to be `char[][count]`; I'm operating on very little sleep)

3) Init an index to 0; for each flag, if it's set, put the appropriate `char[]` into that index, and increment the index.

But why, oh why are you taking the `String` s apart into `char[]` s? The `String` class is your friend. It wants to make your life easier.